# How to remove base site id/context root from URL in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, contextpath

We have a requirement where we need to achieve the following:
We should be redirected to https://localhost:9002/basesiteid/.
But we have a requirement wherein the URL should be resolved to https://localhost:9002/.
Basesite id should not be appended in the URL.

We had the following changes.

```
hac.webroot=/hac
storefront.webroot=
storefrontContextRoot=
```

Also we had made the following changes in URL Encoding Attributes in WCMS->Website.
URL Encoding Attributes

Post the changes we are getting the following error on all the pages,

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: In URL tags, when the "context" attribute is specified, values of both "context" and "url" must start with "/"
```

Is there any anyway how we can remove the basesite id from URL ???

Comment: You haven't mentioned what you have changed in URL Encoding Attributes. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53845362/2478134).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue check the productPrimaryImage.tag for 
`"context="${originalContextPath}"` removing it or setting value to `"/"`  should solve your problem.